# How to represent EAV in CSV?

Tags: database, csv, entity-attribute-value

Assume I have a DB model that supports Entity-Attribute Values. If I had two records that each had multiple EAV entries, for example:

Apple

- Size: small, large
- Color: green, red

Car

- Type: coupe, sedan
- Fuel: diesel, gas

I could make a CSV for apple easy:

```
product, size, color
apple, small, green
apple, small, red
apple, large, green
apple, large, red
```

I could do the same for car, too.

The problem is what if I wanted apple and car to be in the same CSV? Should my CSV headings look like this:

```
product, size, color, type, fuel
```

This doesn't make sense, though. Apples don't have a car type or fuel. And cars don't have a size and color (based on the examples I gave).

Should I employ something like this:

```
product
apple, size:small, color:green
apple, size:small, color:red
apple, size:large, color:green
apple, size:large, color:red
car, type:coupe, fuel:diesel
car, type:coupe, fuel:gas
car, type:sedan, fuel:diesel
car, type:sedan, fuel:gas
```

The consumer of the CSV will just need to know that after the first column are the name-value pairs representing the EAV.

**What's a good approach? Suggestions?**

Comment: Why don't you use different format? E.g. you can use xls and put information about different entities in different sheets.

Comment: This is for an API output. Natively, it will output JSON, but I want to also provide a CSV output option. If there is a standard, I'd like to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I am going to implement:

```
product, name_1, value_1, name_2, value_2
apple, size, small, color, green
apple, size, small, color, red
apple, size, large, color, green
apple, size, large, color, red
car, type, coupe, fuel, diesel
car, type, coupe, fuel, gas
car, type, sedan, fuel, diesel
car, type, sedan, fuel, gas
```

It's probably elegant enough. The consumer of the CVS just needs to know that the name-value pairs follow the pattern "name_x" and "value_x". The list of NVP ends when it reaches the first "name_x" and "value_x" that is empty.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of organizing EAV is:

```
entity,attribute,value
apple,size,small
apple,size,large
apple,color,green
apple,color,red
car,type,coupe
car,type,sedan
car,fuel,gas
car,fuel,diesel
```

The entity is apple or car, each line describes the value of one attribute for the entity on the line.

It isn't a particularly good way of organizing data.  It has some superficial advantages, but it ends up making for complex queries.  However, the alternative design proposed in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28271649/15168) makes life worse.

---

> Say this was a price modifier in a standard e-commerce system. How would I say that a Small Red Apple is $2, but a Small Green Apple is $1?

You have two different entities, so you have to have two different entity identifiers:

```
small-red-apple,price,2
small-green-apple,price,1
```

Or, more usually, you'd have:

```
entity,attribute,value
1112,name,small-red-apple
1112,type,apple
1112,size,small
1112,color,red
1112,price,2
2223,name,small-green-apple,
2223,type,apple
2223,size,small
2223,color,green
2223,price,1
```

That is, entity 1112 describes (or *is*) a small red apple costing $2, while 2223 describes (or *is*) a small green apple costing $1.

Validating EAV data becomes really hard.  How do you ensure that when the 'type' of an entity is 'apple', the 'size' is either 'small' or 'large', and the color is either 'red' or 'green' (but a 'car' can have colors 'black', 'white', and 'blue' too)?  You have to be very careful to identify the 'entity' in each row of an EAV table, and then the attributes that are applicable and the appropriate ranges of values for the attributes.  You can do all that with a (single) EAV table, but it gets messy.

Comment: Say this was a price modifier in a standard e-commerce system. How would I say that a Small Red Apple is $2, but a Small Green Apple is $1?

Comment: You have two different entities, so you have to have two different entity identifiers: `small-red-apple,price,2` and `small-green-apple,price,1`.  Or, more usually, you'd have: `1112,name,small-red-apple`, `1112,type,apple`, `1112,size,small`, `1112,color,red`, `1112,price,2` — and similarly for `2223,name,small-green-apple`, …

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your solution for this price modifier scenario. Can you please edit your answer so I can see your new approach in a properly formatted example, please?